# Sprite Kit unable to pass score, Null Value

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

Im trying to pass score in a very basic way between my game seene and game over scene in my game made in Sprite kit for iOS

first scene

```
SKTransition* reveal = [SKTransition flipHorizontalWithDuration:1.0];
    GameOver* scene = [GameOver sceneWithSize:self.view.bounds.size];

    NSNumber* scoreNum = [NSNumber numberWithInt:score];

    scene.score = scoreNum;
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
    [self.view presentScene:scene transition: reveal];
```

second scene (scene)

```
NSString* scoreMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your Score: %@", self.score.stringValue];
```

I get null every time in the second scene. If i NSLog the NSNumber value in the first scene I get the correct value!

thank you,

Second Scene Property Decloration:

```
@property (strong) NSNumber* score;
```

Comment: In which method in the second scene are you creating the string?

Comment: Why do you need to use an `NSNumber` at all?

Comment: Could you post the property declaration from the GameOver scene?

Comment: Im calling it in initWithSize, Using NSNumber just to get the stringValue easier and I'll post it up!

Comment: Best would be to use a NSInteger or CGFloat in the GameOver scene, then the value will be copied over rather than being passed by reference as with NSNumber

Comment: If you are creating the string in `initWithSize` then you are trying to use it before it is set, which is why it is nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Paulw already stated, you cannot access your passed NSNumber in the scene's init method. You can however access it in the scene's `-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view` method which should be sufficient for your needs.